# How to bring up a list of all products that are currently 'Out of Stock'?

Tags: out-of-stock

```
Magento 1.9.4
```

Is there an easy way to bring up a list of all products that are currently 'Out of Stock'?

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 0)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("eq" => 0));
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Do I put this in CMS - Pages or CMS - Static Blocks or is this like an SQL script one would run on the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this collection to get out of stock products in Magento 1

```
$collection = \Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField(
                'is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0))
        ->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Do I put this in CMS - Pages or CMS - Static Blocks or is this like an SQL script one would run on the database itself?